# Services can't connect to LDAP while using istio in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a kubernetes cluster which has different applications that are supposed to communicate to each other. I am using istio to create a service mesh for all of them.

Problem arises when a service wants to connect to `ldap`. Here is the ldap service definition.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opendj
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: opendj
    helm.sh/chart: opendj-1.0.1
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "4.0.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 4444
      targetPort: 4444
      name: tcp-admin
    - port: 1389
      targetPort: 1389
      name: tcp-ldap
    - port: 1636
      targetPort: 1636
      name: tcp-ldaps
    - port: 8989
      targetPort: 8989
      name: tcp-repl
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: opendj
```

The sidecar is being deployed okay. And I am using istio auto-injection

Here is the error log from ldap

```
WARNING - entrypoint - 2020-02-20 07:15:33,884 - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid network port provided: 0 is not included in the [1, 65535] range.
    at org.opends.server.types.HostPort.normalizePort(HostPort.java:362)
    at org.opends.server.types.HostPort.<init>(HostPort.java:218)
    at org.opends.quicksetup.UserData.setHostName(UserData.java:167)
    at org.opends.quicksetup.UserData.<init>(UserData.java:119)
    at org.opends.server.tools.InstallDS.execute(InstallDS.java:329)
    at org.opends.server.tools.InstallDS.mainCLI(InstallDS.java:268)
    at org.opends.server.tools.InstallDS.mainCLI(InstallDS.java:235)
    at org.opends.quicksetup.installer.SetupLauncher.launch(SetupLauncher.java:108)
    at org.opends.quicksetup.installer.SetupLauncher.main(SetupLauncher.java:55)

INFO - entrypoint - 2020-02-20 07:15:46,581 - Configuring OpenDJ.
WARNING - entrypoint - 2020-02-20 07:15:54,006 - 
Unable to connect to the server at
"istio10-opendj-0.opendj.default.svc.cluster.local" on port 4444
```

Comment: Hi, can You check if its working without headless service? I mean by connecting to  `clusterIP`. Is it working without istio injection?

Comment: I have tried that right now and am still getting the same error